# Missing Twitter, Github, Last Seen, etc from Profile page on Mobile UI

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design, profile-page, mobile-web

The newly re-designed mobile-friendly user profile page does not show links to members important accounts such as *Twitter* and *Github* along with few other minor ones e.g. *Last Seen*, *Member Since, Profile Views* etc. I can understand the reason for missing out (due to the limited real-estate) few *minor* ones but not all the *important* ones. I wonder what could be the reason for this omission.

I don't think displaying *few* of them will clutter the current mobile-friendly UI. There is enough white/empty space in some region to accommodate at least few of the important ones if not all. I frequently use Github and Twitter links to know more about the member. Also, I am a great fan of "*Last Seen*" status and use quite often especially for the members that I follow/observe regularly.

To illustrate this by example, I would like to share the screenshots of StackExchange's employee **Oded** (♦ moderator) profile.

**Current Standard PC Full-Browser Webpage:**

> [image]

The above full-browser webpage screenshot is added for the comparison purpose and just to show what we're missing on mobile UI. Of course, due to the space availability it can accommodate all the information. I agree with it. Notice, how the right-hand side panel shows the links to various important accounts (Twitter, Github, etc.) including of few other useful *user stats*.

**Current Mobile-friendly UI:**

> [image]

Now, lets take a look at the above screenshot of the current mobile-friendly UI. The layout is excellent and did the wonderful job of displaying user's bio-info. along with certain key details from *user stats* section but missed the links to various important accounts (Twitter, Github, etc.) and few minor but useful ones like *Last seen* status. Now, you may think there is hardly any real-estate left on the current layout of mobile UI to accommodate all of these. But that's not completely true. We can still tweak the current mobile layout and add few links without any clutter.

**Proposed Mock-up of Mobile-friendly UI:**

> [image]

As you can see in the above mock-up version, I moved *~294k people reached* to the top row i.e. where the *answers* and *questions* stats are currently displayed. That freed up the space in the middle row which was good enough to accommodate few of the important links e.g. *Twitter*, *Github* along with display of the *Last seen* status. Please ignore the font and icons used in the mock-up version as they are just a placeholder to get an idea.

I do like the new mobile-friendly user profile layout but it could be improved more. Please share your thoughts and discuss any idea(s) that could help improve the current mobile UI.

**P.S.**

Currently, I am using the workaround by clicking on the ***full site*** link located in the footer section which displays a full web browser based page on the mobile. Now I can get *all* the user details I want. But, this (*switching back n forth*) totally defeats the whole purpose of having a mobile-friendly website.

Answer (score 6):

I do like the new design and the omission of a lot of not that relevant fields.

The only one I am missing is the 'last visited' the others I don't really care for, but others might. They do not encourage on-site action as the 'last visited' does.

I would like to see some extra fields, but not all. That might indeed clutter the UI. Is it an option to put those somewhere in the bottom of the page?

Comment: Yes, I agree with you on having an option for "Last Seen..." status at the bottom of page.